# A JSON parsing error occurred, here are the details:

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

**Code**

```
func callAddWithPOST(Name mname:String, PhoneNo mphone:String, Email memail:String, Comment mcomments:String){
var names = [String]()
let login = ["countryId":"1"]
print("Your Result is : = \(login)")
let url = NSURL(string: "http://photokeeper.mgtcloud.co.uk/commonwebservice.asmx/getStateList")!
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
do {
let auth = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(login, options: .PrettyPrinted)
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = auth
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    let badJsonString = "This really isn't valid JSON at all"
    let badJsonData = badJsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    do {
        let parsed = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
        print(parsed)
        let otherParsed = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(badJsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("A JSON parsing error occurred, here are the details:\n \(error)")
    }
print("Done.")
})
task.resume()
} catch {
print("Error")
}}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
    d = "{\"result\":[{\"stateId\":3871,\"stateName\":\"Aberdeenshire\"},{\"stateId\":3872,\"stateName\":\"Anglesey/Sir Fon\"},{\"stateId\":3873,\"stateName\":\"Angus\"},{\"stateId\":3874,\"stateName\":\"Antrim\"},{\"stateId\":3875,\"stateName\":\"Argyll And Bute\"},{\"stateId\":3876,\"stateName\":\"Armagh\"},{\"stateId\":3877,\"stateName\":\"Ayrshire\"},{\"stateId\":3878,\"stateName\":\"Bedfordshire\"},{\"stateId\":3879,\"stateName\":\"Berkshire\"},{\"stateId\":3880,\"stateName\":\"Blaenau Gwent/Blaenau Gwent\"},{\"stateId\":3881,\"stateName\":\"Bristol\"},{\"stateId\":3882,\"stateName\":\"Buckinghamshire\"},{\"stateId\":3883,\"stateName\":\"Caerphilly/Caerffili\"},{\"stateId\":3884,\"stateName\":\"Cambridgeshire\"},{\"stateId\":3885,\"stateName\":\"Cardiff/Caerdydd\"},{\"stateId\":3886,\"stateName\":\"Cardiganshire/Ceredigion\"},{\"stateId\":3888,\"stateName\":\"Carmarthenshire/Sir Gaerfyrddin\"},{\"stateId\":3890,\"stateName\":\"Cheshire\"},{\"stateId\":3891,\"stateName\":\"Clackmannanshire\"},{\"stateId\":3893,\"stateName\":\"Conwy/Conwy\"},{\"stateId\":3895,\"stateName\":\"County Durham\"},{\"stateId\":3896,\"stateName\":\"Cumbria\"},{\"stateId\":3897,\"stateName\":\"Denbighshire/Sir Ddinbych\"},{\"stateId\":3898,\"stateName\":\"Derbyshire\"},{\"stateId\":3899,\"stateName\":\"Devon\"},{\"stateId\":3901,\"stateName\":\"Dorset\"},{\"stateId\":3902,\"stateName\":\"Down\"},{\"stateId\":3904,\"stateName\":\"Dumfries And Galloway\"},{\"stateId\":3905,\"stateName\":\"Dunbartonshire\"},{\"stateId\":3906,\"stateName\":\"Dundee\"},{\"stateId\":3907,\"stateName\":\"Durham/North Yorkshire\"},{\"stateId\":3908,\"stateName\":\"East Lothian\"},{\"stateId\":3909,\"stateName\":\"East Sussex\"},{\"stateId\":3910,\"stateName\":\"East Yorkshire\"},{\"stateId\":3911,\"stateName\":\"Edinburgh\"},{\"stateId\":3912,\"stateName\":\"Essex\"},{\"stateId\":3913,\"stateName\":\"Fermanagh\"},{\"stateId\":3914,\"stateName\":\"Fife\"},{\"stateId\":3915,\"stateName\":\"Flintshire/Sir Fflint\"},{\"stateId\":3917,\"stateName\":\"Glamorgan/Morgannwg\"},{\"stateId\":3918,\"stateName\":\"Glasgow\"},{\"stateId\":3919,\"stateName\":\"Gloucestershire\"},{\"stateId\":3920,\"stateName\":\"Gwynedd/Gwynedd\"},{\"stateId\":3921,\"stateName\":\"Hampshire\"},{\"stateId\":3922,\"stateName\":\"Herefordshire\"},{\"stateId\":3923,\"stateName\":\"Hertfordshire\"},{\"stateId\":3924,\"stateName\":\"Highland\"},{\"stateId\":3925,\"stateName\":\"Kent\"},{\"stateId\":3929,\"stateName\":\"Lanarkshire\"},{\"stateId\":3930,\"stateName\":\"Lancashire\"},{\"stateId\":3932,\"stateName\":\"Leicestershire\"},{\"stateId\":3935,\"stateName\":\"Lincolnshire\"},{\"stateId\":3936,\"stateName\":\"London\"},{\"stateId\":3937,\"stateName\":\"Londonderry\"},{\"stateId\":3940,\"stateName\":\"Manchester\"},{\"stateId\":3943,\"stateName\":\"Merthyr Tydfil/Merthyr Tydfil\"},{\"stateId\":3944,\"stateName\":\"Midlothian\"},{\"stateId\":3946,\"stateName\":\"Monmouthshire/Sir Fynwy\"},{\"stateId\":3947,\"stateName\":\"Moray\"},{\"stateId\":3948,\"stateName\":\"Neath Port Talbot\"},{\"stateId\":3949,\"stateName\":\"Newport\"},{\"stateId\":3950,\"stateName\":\"Norfolk\"},{\"stateId\":3951,\"stateName\":\"Northamptonshire\"},{\"stateId\":3952,\"stateName\":\"Northumberland\"},{\"stateId\":3953,\"stateName\":\"Nottinghamshire\"},{\"stateId\":3955,\"stateName\":\"Orkney\"},{\"stateId\":3956,\"stateName\":\"Oxfordshire\"},{\"stateId\":3957,\"stateName\":\"Pembrokeshire/Sir Benfro\"},{\"stateId\":3958,\"stateName\":\"Perth And Kinross\"},{\"stateId\":3959,\"stateName\":\"Powys/Powys\"},{\"stateId\":3960,\"stateName\":\"Renfrewshire\"},{\"stateId\":3962,\"stateName\":\"Rutland\"},{\"stateId\":3963,\"stateName\":\"Scottish Borders\"},{\"stateId\":3964,\"stateName\":\"Shetland Isles\"},{\"stateId\":3965,\"stateName\":\"Shropshire\"},{\"stateId\":3967,\"stateName\":\"Somerset\"},{\"stateId\":3968,\"stateName\":\"South Yorkshire\"},{\"stateId\":3969,\"stateName\":\"Staffordshire\"},{\"stateId\":3970,\"stateName\":\"Stirling\"},{\"stateId\":3971,\"stateName\":\"Suffolk\"},{\"stateId\":3972,\"stateName\":\"Surrey\"},{\"stateId\":3973,\"stateName\":\"Swansea\"},{\"stateId\":3975,\"stateName\":\"Torfaen\"},{\"stateId\":3976,\"stateName\":\"Tyrone\"},{\"stateId\":3977,\"stateName\":\"Warwickshire\"},{\"stateId\":3979,\"stateName\":\"West Lothian\"},{\"stateId\":3980,\"stateName\":\"West Midlands\"},{\"stateId\":3981,\"stateName\":\"West Sussex\"},{\"stateId\":3982,\"stateName\":\"West Yorkshire\"},{\"stateId\":3983,\"stateName\":\"Western Isles\"},{\"stateId\":3987,\"stateName\":\"Wiltshire\"},{\"stateId\":3988,\"stateName\":\"Worcestershire\"},{\"stateId\":3989,\"stateName\":\"Wrexham\"}],\"status\":\"success\"}";
}
```

A JSON parsing error occurred, here are the details:
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
Done.

I AM GETTING ERROR - `Invalid value around character 0.`  I want to get data in proper format with desired key and value, will anybody please help me to fix this issues.

Comment: can you paste restclient response ??

Comment: you can check your json data is valid or not [HERE](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```
if let result:String = parsed["d"]! {
    let result = convertStringToDictionary(text: result)
    print("Converted result = \(result)")
}

//SWIFT 3
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

//SWIFT 2
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        do {
            return try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response is corrupted. Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) to verify it.

Convert it from

```
{\"result\":[{\"stateId\":3871,\"stateName\":\"Aberdeenshire\"}
```

to

```
{
    "result": {
        "stateId": 3871,
        "stateName": "Aberdeenshire"
    }
}
```

Notice the removal of the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting `String` in your response, so try something like this.

```
do {
    let parsed = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]
    let responseStr = parsed["d"] as! String
    let correctData = responseStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let responseDic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(correctData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]
    print(responseDic)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print("A JSON parsing error occurred, here are the details:\n \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Variable used within its own initial value -> for variable ‘ correctData ’ 

Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ‘:’  for line ->   catch let error as NSError {

Comment: Sorry by mistake added `{` bracket after that just remove it, check my edited answer.

Comment: getting error ->  Use of unresolved identifier ’NSUTF8StringEncoding’    in  line  ->  let correctData = responseStr.dataUsingEncodi‌​ng(NSUTF8StringEncodi‌​ng)

Comment: yes, i was even getting error, so i have changed the logic through different code. and done with it

Comment: What error you are talking about, now there is no problem with code.

Comment: yes you are right there may not be any prob with the code. but it may be because of other lines i was getting code that i had mentioned before. to i have changed my  whole code. so no need to worry. thanks for being with me.

Comment: @HardikChavda If this help you than please accept the answer by tapping True icon beside my answer. [Like this way you can accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)